# ReactJS using axios post keep giving me error 400(bad request)

Tags: reactjs, post, axios

I am keeping get this error for send post request by axios in ReactJS.
My code is like:

```
const params = JSON.stringify({
      "email": "someEmail@gmail.com",
      "name": "Some Name",
      "password": "123qwe!!"
    });

axios.post('localhost:8080/users', params, {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    )
      .then(response => {
        console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ",response);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
      })
```

I used same data to test my api in postman and it worked.
Somebody please help me!!

Comment: keep getting this error: AXIOS ERROR:  Error: Request failed with status code 400
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at settle (settle.js:17)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleLoad (xhr.js:62)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to `JSON.stringify` your 'params'.
Change it into:

```js
const params = {
  email: "someEmail@gmail.com",
  name: "Some Name",
  password: "123qwe!!"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use this one-
axios.post('http://localhost:8080/users', params, {
headers: {
'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
}

Answer (score 0):

axios signature for post is `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`.
so your code must be like this:

```
const loginData= {
      "email": "someEmail@gmail.com",
      "name": "Some Name",
      "password": "123qwe!!"
    }

axios.post('localhost:8080/users', null, {
      params:loginData,
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
    )
      .then(response => {
        console.log("RESPONSE RECEIVED: ",response);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log("AXIOS ERROR: ", err);
      })
```